# xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed when HDMI monitor not detected

Tags: drivers, 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

sometimes my PC doesn't detect the display connected on HDMI. Other display, VGA, is always detected and functional.
I'm using integraded graphics card (Intel i5-4460 CPU), no separate graphics card.

So, sometimes HDMI works as it should, but sometimes it's not recognized.

```
user@Home-PC:~$ xrandr
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00
user@Home-PC:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --right-of VGA-1 
user@Home-PC:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "1920x1080" 
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

I tried `arandr`but that only shows VGA display, and HDMI is greyed out.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First, use `xrandr --verbose` to figure out what you're dealing with.

No guarantees but specifying the crtc number may resolve things -- especially if you're using multiple external monitors.

If one crtc number doesn't work try another. For example, a situation with laptop video at crtc 0 and `xrandr --verbose` output indicating 0 1 2 are options for DP-1 (an external monitor connected via VGA), crtc 1 failed.

```
$ xrandr --output DP-1 --crtc 1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1366x0 --rotate normal
/usr/bin/xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

Trying again with 2 solved the problem:

```
$ xrandr --output DP-1 --crtc 2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1366x0 --rotate normal
```